# How can I store files in an archive without compressing them?

Tags: software-recommendation, compression

I need to store files in archives, but not compress them.

The archive manager takes too long, and I can't find an option to only store (not compress) files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm talking about storing in an archive file (without compression). Such option exists in some archive/compression software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest and easiest method to create an uncompressed [**tar** archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29) is a Nautilus context menu installed by default.

After selection of a directory or files press the right mouse button to select *"Compress..."* from the context menu. In the following window choose **.tar** from the dropdown list, give a sensible name and a storage location for the archive, then press *Create*.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

### Use the *Tar uncompressed (.tar)* format in Archive Manager

The screenshots below explain it:

#### In 10.04:

[image]

#### In 12.04:

[image]

#### In 14.04:

[image]

Comment: Just realised this myself, saves answering it- thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use 7zip utility.
[image]

> **Warning:** 7-zip does NOT preserve Unix file permissions!

Once installed,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
7z a -t7z /home/user/home/pictures/pics.7z /home/user/home/pictures -mx0
```

The example above: Lets assume that you want to add all the files in the pictures folder, into an archive named pics, with no compression (store Only) and you want the file to be stored in the same folder.

Where is the folder or file you want to archive? ***/home/user/home/pictures***

In which folder, do you want the output file(s) to be placed? ***/home/user/home/pictures***

What would you like to name the output file(s)? ***pics***

What level of compression do you want?  ***No Compression***

Comment: This definitely works, but what's the advantage over **tar** if you're not using compression, especially since you lose your file permissions?

Comment: It's just a way to store files into an archive without compression.

Comment: Why the down-vote? :)

Answer (score 4):

The .tar format, which Archive Manager supports, will do this for you.

The .tar format by itself will store multiple files in a container, without any compression.

Most decent archiving software, even for Windows and Mac, will understand .tar files.